# Is there any investigation going concerning goldPseudo?

Tags: support

<del>Moderator goldPseudo is a very active moderator, as well as a very experienced user in stackexchange.</del>

<del>However, I have recently experienced some **oppressive behavior** coming from **moderator goldPseudo**.</del>

<del>It appears that this individual is targeting people who ask questions, write comments/answers that **may or may not question/conflict with his sectarian point of view of Islam**. And by targeting I mean: repetitively downvoting, putting on hold/closing topics and deleting comments, all this using "unrelated reasons" such as "unclear".</del>

<del>He has also showed **grudge holding behaviour** **when dealing with specific users** such as myself.</del>

<del>Reading through **other complaints** about this guy, I found myself in the exact same case.</del>

<del>Now my question:
**Is Stackexchange team taking any actions to look into this issue? Any investigation going?**</del>

<del>Thank you.</del>

Now I'd like to apologise to goldPseudo, it seems to me that I, along with many others, have accused him wrongly as he is only trying to be just in *this place*.

The problem is this,

- Take the original Islam (from the Words of God)
- Add to it couple other books (Hadiths)
- Season it with a little bit of misinterpretations and alternations of other books
- Mix it with traditions
- Blend everything with a big cup of superstitions
- Carefully pour it around the globe

You get to taste this by sitting in front of your computer and opening SE Islam while taking a sip of your morning coffee trying not to Laugh, or cry, or smack the keyboard with your head.

Before I ask for an account deletion, I want to apologise again to goldPseudo and everyone involved. I now understand the challenge that moderators face in this place.

May The Divine guide us all to the One Path that Abraham, Moses, Jesus and Muhammad preached and keep us away from the human sects.

Amen.

Comment: We get regular complaints about goldPseudo and I have yet to see any reason to [remove him](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/1372/138). At this point, I pretty much assume that people who raise these complaints misunderstand the [purpose of the site](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1157/138). However, if you have a specific (and ideally, new) concern to share, please edit the question and ping me. I'll take a look.

Comment: I mean specific actions on the site performed as a moderator that you object to. It's all well and good to say a moderator is biased, but unless there's an example of the moderator using their position to harm the site, there's nothing to investigate.

Comment: Fron your comment i've got the certain impression that you missunderstood the stackexchange model in general and the purpose of this site in special.

Comment: Moderating itself is not an easy task anyone could do mistakes as an administrator ,The moderator has deleted some of my answers or edited too which at once no one likes but if you deeply look into the cause and understand the site values so to be honest I have realized he did fairly well and doing great job here.

Comment: The second example is what i might call a standard clean up of a "comment discussion" made by a mod this is something i'd call usuall on any SE site i konw. As the answer has been edited to fit your input your comments afterwards are no more necessary as one could see the development if the post in the edit history.

Comment: Neither of your examples is particularly unreasonable behavior for moderators. Deleting comments is pretty normal, especially comments that address downvoters. You might consider editing the results of the first discussion into the goat question. As an outsider, it seems like maybe your question is what I call a [stump-the-chumps question](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/394/68) in which you already know the answer and are just testing other people on the site. I'd consider a [self-answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and a question edit, if I were you.

Comment: Stumbled by chance upon this question. One of the reasons I don't ask and answer here is indeed the user the IP is complaining about. It's demotivating and I don't enjoy this site (Islam Exchange) because of that.